# JCMD command is not listing the java process

Tags: java, jvm, jfr, jcmd

I have a java process named app created under abc user. Now, when I am executing the jcmd command as abc user to list the java processes, it is not listing the app. At the same time, `ps aux | grep java` command is listing it. Only jcmd command has the issue.

Comment: You can use `jps` to list java processes. I am not aware what `jcmd` is for

Comment: Thanks. But,I need to use jcmd because I have to get the JFR.

Comment: Java process is started as a jar under the same user in which jcmd is grouped.

Comment: Which JDK version and OS?

Comment: I am using JDK 11 and linux OS